# Incremental backup Linux command

Tags: linux

What is the command to do a incremental backup?  Any source or any links would be much appreciated.

Comment: This question is more appropriate for superuser.com, IMHO.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) is what you are looking for. [Here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-spunix_rsync/index.html) is a nice tutorial.

Comment: This question was about an incremental backup. The Wikipedia article you linked to (and other sources I've found) say it's a differential backup.

Answer (score 12):

Depending on what you need from your backups, [rdiff-backup](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/) may be what you want. It's based on the same idea as rsync, but also keeps historical backups (in a space-efficient manner, by storing the differences).

Answer (score 4):

[Dirvish](http://www.dirvish.org/) makes incremental snapshots (that look as full directories trees, thanks to the magic of hardlinks), using rysnc under the hood. It works well for me.

Comment: But the latest news on the dirvish page is from 2008.

Comment: Thanks @leonbloy, but I'd hoped you were linking to something telling me Dirvish was a mature project that didn't need updating or some other source saying it had been updated. As it is, the article you link to merely says that a lack of updates does not mean a product as bad - I don't disagree with this. But most projects have some low level of activity as maturity is an asymptotic rather than absolute state. Without such activity it is valid to wonder about the state of a project; especially when back-ups are concerned.

Comment: @Richard Even more apt in this case, the news says there was an experimental version released in 2005, so presumably the dev(s) thought there _was_ something more to do. This version still hasn't seen a proper release, 9 years later.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the command I use for incremental backups of my virtual machine using rsync.

```
rsync -avh --delete --progress --link-dest="/Volumes/canteloup/vm_backups/`ls -1tr /Volumes/canteloup/vm_backups/ | tail -1`" "/Users/julian/Documents/Parallels" "/Volumes/canteloup/vm_backups/`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S`"
```

`-avh` means make an **a**rchive, with **v**erbose output in a **h**uman readable form.

`--delete` will make sure each incremental backup does not contain files that have been deleted since the last backup. It means the backup taken on a particular date will be a snapshot of the directory as it was on that date.

`--progress` will display in the terminal the amount transferred, the percentage, and the time remaining for each file. Handy for virtual machine backups with 40Gb+ file sizes.

`--link-dest` specifies the directory to use for making links for the files that haven't changed. It uses `ls -rt | tail -1` to get the last file. Seems to be fine if the file doesn't exist, as in the first time it is run.

The next arg is the directory to backup.

The last arg is the target directory. The name is a timestamp.

Comment: this looks like a good idea, especially with the `ls -rt | tail -1` - that saves time writing a bash script to check for the last date?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following bash script. Please replace `src` and `dest` with the source and destination you want to use. If you are not backing up in a local storage then remove `--inplace` (This option is useful for transfer of large files with block-based changes or appended data, and also on systems that are disk bound, not network bound. you should also not use this option to update files that are being accessed by others).

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -ab --dry-run --stats --human-readable --inplace --debug=NONE --log-file=rsync.log --backup-dir=rsync_bak.$(date +"%d-%m-%y_%I-%M-%S%P") --log-file-format='%t %f %o %M' --delete-after src dest | sed -e '1d;5,12d;14,17d'

echo -e "\nDo you want to continue?"

while true; do
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) rsync -ab --human-readable --inplace --info=PROGRESS2,BACKUP,DEL --debug=NONE --log-file=rsync.log --backup-dir=rsync_bak.$(date +"%d-%m-%y_%I-%M-%S%P") --log-file-format='%t %f %o %M' --delete-after src dest; break;;
        [Nn]* ) exit;;
        * ) read -p "Please answer yes or no: " yn;;
    esac
done
```